# Array of Pointers to Strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Write a prog to reverse the strings stored in the following array of pointers to strings:

char *array_str_ptr={
                      "Brinda Roy"
                      "Rakesh Baid"
                      "Neha Saxena"
                      "Ankit Jain"
                    }

Comment: Nice homework assignment. Hope you figure it out. Good luck!

Comment: [hahaha](http://www.scribd.com/doc/65100585/C-Assingments-Day5)

Comment: A little pointer to the rules of SO: We love to help you if you get stuck. But only after you prove to be capable of helping yourself. We are not here to do your work for you. Furthermore: 'Reverse'. Reverse what? The order? To a different type? The letters?

Comment: @RefugnicEternium that's what, i didnt get it. by the way i'm good at C, i learned C in 11th std, bt now i'm stuck with this 'array of pointers to strings'. I guess it's to reverse the order of strings

Comment: @ibi0tux thx, bt is that site a good one??? and may i have the solns

Comment: `char *array_str_ptr[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question was neither closed nor answered, here are two possible approaches:

'Reverse the order of strings:

```
char *array_str_ptr={ "Brinda Roy", "Rakesh Baid", "Neha Saxena", "Ankit Jain" };
char *Reversed[4];

for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    Reversed[i] = array_str_ptr[4-i];
```

This approach copies the pointer references in reverse order into another buffer.

'Reverse to string' -> This is a C++-approach, since it makes use of the std::container `string`

```
#include <string>
char *array_str_ptr={ "Brinda Roy", "Rakesh Baid", "Neha Saxena", "Ankit Jain" };
std::string Strings[4];

for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    Strings[i] = array_str_ptr[i];
```

'Reverse to string' -> Makes one string of the different elements.

```
char *array_str_ptr={ "Brinda Roy", "Rakesh Baid", "Neha Saxena", "Ankit Jain" };
char Buf[50];

Buf[0] = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    strcat(Buf, array_str_ptr[i]);
```

This one will concatenate the four strings into one long string without any spaces or the likes. The are more elaborate ways to do this, but this one's the quickest.

Regarding the task at hand: Why don't you ask the one who gave you this assignment, what they actually meant? It may save you from comments like the ones above.